# Vue. Set focus on a component's input when value in Vuex store is modified

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So this is the code I have in my component:

```
//template
<v-select ref='ItemSearchSelect' :options="options"></v-select>
...
//script
created: function () {            
         this.$store.subscribe((setFocusSearch, state) => {
                if (setFocusSearch.type == 'setFocusSearch' && setFocusSearch.payload == true){
                    this.$refs.ItemSearchSelect.$refs.search.focus()
                    this.$store.commit('setFocusSearch',false)                    
                }
        })
    },
```

This is my store mutation, which can be called from any other component:

```
setFocusSearch(state,val){
      state.focussearch = val;
    },
```

Sometimes it's working correctly, but other times I can see this error in console, and the focus is not working:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined
    at eval (ItemSearch.vue?d78c:38)
    at eval (vuex.esm.js?2f62:392)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Store.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:392)
    at Store.boundCommit [as commit] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:335)
    at VueComponent.focusSearch (ShoppingCart.vue?0f5b:96)
    at keydown (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?
    ...
```

It always happens in this case:

Router push to a a view with my ItemSearch component and the component that triggers the store mutation. At this moment everything is working fine. Now I router push to another view that has nothing to do, and then I go back with router push to the original view. At this moment, when the mutation is triggered, I get the error.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your component is unmounted / destroyed, the mutation subscription will live on in the store. This is why the `this` reference in your subscriber becomes `undefined`.

What you need to do is remove the subscription when your component is destroyed. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe...

> To stop subscribing, call the returned unsubscribe function.

For example

```js
mounted () {
  // the name isn't really important and since this isn't a reactive property,
  // you don't need to have this defined in "data"
  this.focusSearchUnsubscriber = this.$store.subscribe(...)
},
beforeDestroy () {
  this.focusSearchUnsubscriber() // call the unsubscribe function
}
```

You'll note I've also used `mounted` instead of `created`. This is because your `$refs` won't be populated until your component is mounted so using the later lifecycle hook adds a bit of extra safety.